# Как цикл может выйти за массив в этом коде?

Tags: python, python-3.x

При запуске этого кода, получаю исключение вида

```
if(objects[obj] is objects[i]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Но как это происходит?

```
ans = 0
objects = [1,2]
for obj in objects: # доступная переменная objects
   for i in objects:
       if(objects[obj] is objects[i]):
           continue
       else:
           if obj != i:
               asn = asn + 1

print(ans)
```

Comment: for obj in objects => obj = 1, затем 2. objects[2] => ошибка

Comment: Кстати, помимо лишнего `else`, вы понимаете суть оператора `is`?

Comment: а какое значение `ans` вы хотите увидеть `print(ans)` ?

Comment: @S.Nick количество различных объектов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно ответ на вопрос "почему цикл выходит за массив" можно легко получить выводя на печать индексы (в данном случае можно и в уме, но с печатью проще). Добавим строчку

```
ans = 0
objects = [1,2]
for obj in objects: # доступная переменная objects
   for i in objects:
       print(obj, i) # <- вот эту
       if(objects[obj] is objects[i]):
           continue
       else:
           if obj != i:
               asn = asn + 1

print(ans)
```

Вывод:

```
1 1
1 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lesha\Desktop\as.py", line 6, in <module>
    if(objects[obj] is objects[i]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Вот все и понятно. В списке у нас всего два элемента, номер последнего - 1. Поэтому попытка обращения к индексу 2 приводит к такой ошибке.

Comment: а как мне реализовать сравнение одного элемента со всеми в массиве? Я просто до этого на пайтоне не писал, вот и мучаюсь